# Semaphores: Critical Section with priorities

Tags: java, synchronization, semaphore, critical-section

I'm writing a program in Java that deals with Semaphores for an assignment. I'm still new to the idea of Semaphores and concurrency. 
The description of the problem is as follows:

1. A vector V[] of booleans. V[i] is "True"if Pi needs to use the critical section.
2. A vector of binary semaphores B[] to block processes from entering their critical section: B[i] will be the semaphore blocking process Pi.
3. A special scheduler process SCHED is used whenever a blocked process needs to be awakened to use the critical section.
4. SCHED is blocked by waiting on a special semaphore S
5. When a process Pi needs to enter the critical section, it sets V[i] to "True", signals the semaphore S and then waits on the semaphore B[i].
6. Whenever SCHED is unblocked, it selects the process Pi with the smallest index i for which V[i] is "True". Process Pi is then awakened by signaling B[i] and SCHED goes back to sleep by blocking on semaphore S.
7. When a process Pi leaves the critical section, it signals S.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Process extends Thread {
    static boolean V[];
    int i;
    static Semaphore B[]; //blocking semaphore
    static Semaphore S;
    private static int id;
    static int N;
    static int insist = 0;

    public static void process (int i, int n) {
       id = i;
       N = n;
       V = new boolean[N];
    }

    private void delay () {
       try {
        sleep (random(500));
        }
        catch (InterruptedException p) {
        }
    }

    private static int random(int n) {
        return (int) Math.round(n * Math.random() - 0.5);
    }

    private void entryprotocol(int i) {
         V[Process.id] = true;
         int turn = N;
         while (V[Process.id] == true && turn == N) {
           System.out.println("P" + Process.id + " is requesting critical section");
           signal(S);
         }
        critical(Process.id);
        wait(B[Process.id]);
        V[Process.id] = false;
        }



   private void wait(Semaphore S) {
       if (Process.id > 0) {
        Process.id--;
      } else {
        //add Process.id to id.queue and block
        wait(B[Process.id]);
       }
   }

     private void signal(Semaphore S) {
         if (B[Process.id] != null) {
          Sched(Process.id);
        } else {
          Process.id++; //remove process from queue
          critical(Process.id); //wakes up current process
         }
     }

    private void critical(int i) {
        System.out.println("P" + Process.id + " is in the critical section");
        delay();
        exitprotocol(i);
     }

    private void exitprotocol(int i) {
        System.out.println("P" + Process.id + " is leaving the critical section");
        V[id] = false;
        signal(S);
    }

     public void Sched(int i) {
         if (B[Process.id] == null) {
        signal(B[Process.id]);
        }
        wait(S);
     }

     public void run() {
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Sched(i);
           entryprotocol(Process.id);
           try {
              wait(Process.id);
          }
           catch (InterruptedException p) {
            }
          signal(S);
        }
         }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int N = 5;

        Process p[] = new Process[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        p[i] = new Process();
        p[i].start();
        }
        }
   }
```

I believe my logic here is correct but I'm getting a lot of errors (such as Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException). Can any shed some light on what I'm doing wrong & provide me with some help. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: 'A lot of errors' such as what?

Comment: a lot of nullpointerexception. that's actually the only errors i'm getting at the moment

Comment: A stacktrace is usually very helpful in finding the problem in such cases.

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Answer (score 4):

Your `NPE` is probably due to the fact that you never initialize your Semaphore array - but its hard to say without a proper stack trace.

Two pieces of advice:

1) You might want to give your class variables more meaningful names than :
    B
    N
    S
    V.
Imagine walking away from this project and revisiting it in 4 months and had to read through that.

2) Figure out your class model on on a white board before writing any code.  You have methods that take semaphores with the same name as some of your static fields.  What are the relationships of the objects in your program?  If you don't know, odds are your program doesn't know either.

Comment: thanks for those suggestions. is there anything else you suggest that i do because i am completely stumped

Comment: Did you try initializing the Semaphore array?  Paste your stack trace in the question

Comment: ahhhh i figured it out actually. i'm dealing with the array index being out of bounds now but thanks a bunch